# regex pattern to capture same value in multiple group

Tags: regex

I have the below regex and I want to group like below

https://abc.xyz.com/path1/path2/path3/path4

group1:path1/path2/path3/path4...
group2:path1/path2
group3:path2/path3/path4...

where path1 and path2 are constant

i tried

/((path1/path2).*)/gm

am expecting

```
group1:path1/path2/path3/path4...
group2:path1/path2
group3:path2/path3/path4...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place a capture group in a positive lookahead assertion to allow partially overlapping sets of sequences to be captured into different groups:

```
((path1/(?=(path2.*))path2).*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ayt3f5/3

In the interest of following the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you can also avoid repetition of `path2` by using a backreference, although this would require creating a group 4:

```
((path1/(?=((path2).*))\4).*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ayt3f5/4

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use a different grouping criteria, since creating an overlap in capture groups complicates the regex.

The regex `((path1/(path2))(.*))` almost yields the desired result. The only thing we need to do is stitch group 3 `path2` and group 4 `.*` together using the programming language you're working with.

Here is an example using JavaScript:

```js
const url = "https://abc.xyz.com/path1/path2/path3/path4";
const regex = /((path1\/(path2))(.*))/;

const match = url.match(regex);
if (match) {
  match[3] += match.pop();
  
  console.log("entire match:", match[0]);
  console.log("capute groups:", match.slice(1));
}
```